# Using hidden fields in rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best practice using hidden fields in html views?

In my html.erb I need to check if a value exists,  if it does then u want to ensure a button remains disabled.

Can I set a hidden field in ruby code like this ;

```
<% if @is_draft %>
<input type="hidden" id="isdraft "value="true"><% end %>
```

Then can I access this in my jquery code?

Is this accepted practice? Note that the javascript is in its own file,  the script is not in the html.erb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is regarded as pretty poor practice most of the time.

Instead it is usually better to render the button as disabled on the server side after checking the condition.
Also make sure to sanitize the requests made by this form (button is clicked although your condition does not permit it). Users could un-disable the button and click it.

If you find that you have to save some information in HTML for whatever reason, I would resort to data-*-attributes!

Hope that helps!

EDIT pseudocode example:

```
# MyView.html.erb
<% unless @is_draft %>
   <%= render partial: 'my_checkbox_button_enabling', format: [:js] %>
<% end %>

<%= button_tag "My nice button", disabled: true, id: "my-button" %>
```

Comment: The issue is that the button is disabled by default,  and can be enabled by checking any checkbox on a row.  But only if @If_draft is false, so I need to check the value of this variable in my jquery js file...

Comment: If you ask me, just put the enabling-disabling onclick handlers for your checkboxes into a JS file, and only render it when @if_draft is false. This way you only have that behavior in that case. Does that work for you?

Comment: Not sure what you mean,  but the users want to see the button at all times.  I disable it by default when the page renders by using css. So the button is greyed out when the page Loads, as no check boxes will be checked.  But if @is_draft is true,  the button should not be enabled at all no matter which check box is checked..

Comment: Give me a second, I'll update my answer with some pseudo code to give you an idea.